# RSA-Encryption, How to find private key (d) knowing public key (n) (e) & knowing how big the cypher text is (88 digits)?

Tags: encryption, rsa

How do i crack given n as `n = 4099430871402176635782717535427267202018459295862032363925221458393907152187479623765591`

and e as `e = 659427`

also knowing that the cyphertext is 88 digits long (it is not 88. the cyphertext itself has 88 digits similar to n)?? I have found programs that can do this however i must know how to do it by hand if possible. And those that explain it by hand i cant seem to understand. So if possible, a simplistic version would be very nice. Please and thanks.

Comment: That's a 291-bit integer. IIRC this is on the upper end of where you'd use the quadratic sieve. Oh and these numbers would take too long to do anything interesting by hand.

Comment: [CADO-NFS](http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/) factors this number in less than one hour of CPU time. The prime factors are $102256052471$, $137900704561519857217233115935757$, and $290715414070621810383039660471428513788122853$.